# How can I bring the Excel window to the foreground after automating Internet Explorer?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I've seen similar questions asked before but there has never been a clear solution.  I'm trying to bring the Excel window into focus in the foreground without closing Internet Explorer and it works perfectly fine in Debug mode but not when actually running it.  I've tried `AppActivate "Excel"` already but that just makes the Excel icon at the bottom of the screen blink.  Then I found this but I can't get it working

```
Declare PtrSafe Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" _
            (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Global Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long



Sub qstn()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer: IE.navigate "www.cnn.com": IE.Visible = True: apiShowWindow IE.hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
LoadIt IE

SetForegroundWindow Application.hWnd

End Sub

Sub LoadIt(ByVal IE As InternetExplorer, Optional ByVal loadmins As Integer = 5)


Do
    DoEvents

Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And IE.Busy = False

End Sub
```

Comment: `AppActivate Application.Caption`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sub test()
    AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
End Sub
```